# Visual Studio Code- Android SDK can not be found

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I am using visual studio code to create a mobile app for my club at school. I downloaded the android sdk but when I set the ANDROID_HOME variable to where the sdk was located, I got this as an error:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.13, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
  10.0.17134.407], locale en-US)
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
  X ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\shant\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
  but Android SDK not found at this location.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[!] Android Studio
  X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
  X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
  X android-studio-dir = /path/to/android/studio
  X Android Studio not found at /path/to/android/studio
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.3)
[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

I was thinking that I should try and redownload it but im not too sure what to do. Please, anything helps. Thank you.

Comment: I see a space in your ANDROID_HOME environment variable. Remove the space. You may need to relogin for changes to take.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I doubled checked and the space was just a mistake I made copying and pasting

Comment: Oops, just realized that your SDK path is too far into the SDK. It should stop before platforms. ..Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: @MorrisonChang I tried that already but I still get the same problem

Comment: Update your question with the path to  the Android SDK along with updated flutter doctor output.

Comment: Can you post a list of what your folder "C:\Users\shant\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" contains?